# Use trait associations in a custom strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have built a custom strategy for FactoryGirl, but unfortunately traits that are passed to this strategy and contain association are oddly handled - if I have an association defined for trait A, it is there for trait B as well, even if it doesn't define it. Here's an example:

```
factory :debtor_steps, class: Debtor do
    trait :first do
      association :party
    end

    trait :last do
      association :branch
      status_reason_code 1
    end
end
```

And some sample output:

```
(byebug) FactoryGirl.build_attributes_for(:debtor_steps)
{:party_id=>nil, :branch_id=>nil}
(byebug) FactoryGirl.build_attributes_for(:debtor_steps, :first)
{:party_id=>2, :branch_id=>nil}
(byebug) FactoryGirl.build_attributes_for(:debtor_steps, :last)
{:status_reason_code=>1, :party_id=>nil, :branch_id=>2}
```

The custom strategy is built on `build` and basically extracts a hash of the built object (similar to `attributes_for` but with foreign keys).

As you can see, associations are there even if the used trait doesn't define it. How can I solve this?

Comment: are these associations real on your model? in which case - they are indeed always there, just set to nil.

Comment: Yes, they are on my model, but I would like only to generate attributes for the fields I've defined in the factory.

Comment: Because they are in your model - the attributes are always there. whether you generate them or not. you shouldn't be testing for whether the attribute is defined-on-the-model or not... you should test whether the attribute is nil or present... in which case it doesn't matter if it's defined or not

Comment: But then, why can you define an association on a factory since it is always assumed to be there?

Comment: You aren't defining it - you are telling the Factory that there is an association by that name on your model of that name. The association was defined in your model.

Comment: OK, but it still doesn't make sense. If the association is always there, there is no point in telling FactoryGirl about it. If you have the possibility to tell FactoryGirl about it, it should be used only when you state so.

Comment: FactoryGirl doesn't automatically introspect on your model to figure out what associations are there or not - that's why you have to tell it. However - on your real model, the association is always there, so whether or not factorygirl knows about it - your code should always be able to deal with the fact that these associations are always there.